# Spfx NoJS framework question with using plugin

Tags: javascript, spfx-webparts

I'm working on a spfx webpart and using NoJS for it.
The webpart is an imageslider with carousel.

I'm going to be using the plugin [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tgcpey0m/)

The plugin is [FancyApps](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/getting-started)

The issue is how to bind the plugin using jquery in my code below

```
public render(): void {
    this.domElement.innerHTML = `
   <div>
      <a
         data-fancybox="gallery"
         data-src="https://lipsum.app/id/2/1024x768">
        <img src="https://lipsum.app/id/2/200x150" />
      </a>

      <a data-fancybox="gallery" data-src="https://lipsum.app/id/3/1024x768">
        <img src="https://lipsum.app/id/3/200x150" />
      </a>

      <a data-fancybox="gallery" data-src="https://lipsum.app/id/4/1024x768">
        <img src="https://lipsum.app/id/4/200x150" />
      </a>
    </div>`;
    
  }

  public constructor() {
    super();
    //SPComponentLoader.loadCss('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    let cssURL = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@5.0/dist/fancybox/fancybox.css";
    SPComponentLoader.loadCss(cssURL);
    SPComponentLoader.loadScript("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js");
    SPComponentLoader.loadScript("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@5.0/dist/fancybox/fancybox.umd.js");
    SPComponentLoader.loadScript("https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/demoportal/SiteAssets/customScripts/SlideBind.js");
   

    }
```

As you can see below i'm using the SPComponentLoader to load the script.
The last one SlideBind.js is where i'm calling the plugin like below

```
    $.Fancybox.bind("[data-fancybox]", {
  // Your custom options
});
```

But when test my webpart my running gulp serve the images load fine and everything but in the console i get this error
[image]

How can I reference this as i can't see any other way in the instructions.

Thanks in advance